# Laravel Cashier & Laravel Passport - Can't Call both Traits

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create an API. Using Laravel Cashier(With Stripe) & Laravel Passport.

```
    public $successStatus = 200;
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 401);
    }
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
    $user = Auth::user();
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    $success['name'] = $user->name;
    $success['email'] = $user->email;
    $stripeToken = 'tok_visa';
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env(STRIPE_SECRET));

    try
    {
        $user->newSubscription('monthly')->create($stripeToken, [
            'email' => $user->email, 'description' => 'Our First Customer'
        ]);

        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this->successStatus);
    }

"message": "Call to a member function createToken() on null",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
"file": "/Users/Taylor/Documents/Websites/storingcompany/api/app/Http/Controllers/Register.php",
"line": 32,
"trace": [
```

Is there something That I am missing here? I am not able to call the Billable model trait from the user. In my controller it shows newSubscription not found in Authentiable instead of Billable.

My user Class:

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;



class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Billable;
use HasApiTokens;
use Notifiable;
```

Comment: do you get an error, what is the error if you do, what is actually happening ... what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: I get the error as above, I am trying to new stripe subscription through the billable trait on my user model but it tells me it can not found under authentatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't because of not 'using' a trait, this is because the `$user` variable is `null`.

You have a line of code that creates a new User record in the database. The immediate next line, you are trying to get the current authenticated user. I would assume this is some registration or signup process so there wouldn't be an authenticated user as they don't exist in the system yet.

```
$user = User::create(...);
$user = Auth::user();  // what do you expect this to be, besides `null`

$user->anyMethodEver(); // Call to a member function ... on null.
```

Comment: Thanks your answer! Pretty silly thing I missed. I am used to having the User already Authenticated when making theses calls like $user = $request->user().